# Kendo grid Inline cell edit is not editing double value

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I have grid inside two `nullable double values` and i want to edit them.When i click editable cell and write number and passing next cell unfortunately the cell i edited before is not editing

Here is my grid view

```
                @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Orpac.Controllers.SettingController.StationLocations>()
                .Name("Coordinates").AutoBind(false)
                .DataSource(dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax()
                .Read("GridStationLocationsBinding", "Setting").Update("UpdateStationLocationsBinding", "Setting")
                .Model(keys =>
                {
                    keys.Id(c => c.StationId);
                    keys.Field(c => c.StationCode).Editable(false);
                    keys.Field(c => c.StationName).Editable(false);
                    keys.Field("Lat", typeof(double?)).Editable(true);
                    keys.Field("Lon", typeof(double?)).Editable(true);
                }).Batch(true).ServerOperation(false)
                )
                .Editable(editing => editing.Mode(Kendo.Mvc.UI.GridEditMode.InCell))
                .ToolBar(commands =>
                {

                    commands.Save();
                    commands.Excel().HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "btnexcel" }).Text(" ").IconClass("k-i-excel");
                    commands.Custom().Text(" ").HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "btnadd", id = "importcoordinates1", href = "#", tooltip = "Import Station Coordinates", onclick = "importcoordinateswin()" });
                })
                .Excel(excel => excel.FileName((string)ViewData["StationLocations"] + ".xlsx").AllPages(true).Filterable(true))
                .Columns(columns =>
                {
                    columns.Bound(e => e.StationId).Visible(false);
                    columns.Bound(e => e.StationCode).Width(100).Title((string)ViewData["Code"]);
                    columns.Bound(e => e.StationName).Width(200).Title((string)ViewData["Station"]);
                    columns.Bound(e => e.Lat).Width(100).Title((string)ViewData["Lat"]);
                    columns.Bound(e => e.Lon).Width(100).Title((string)ViewData["Lon"]);
                })
                .Sortable()
                .Filterable(filterable => filterable
                .Extra(false)
                .Operators(operators => operators
                    .ForString(str => str.Clear()
                        .StartsWith((string)ViewData["Startswith"])
                        .Contains((string)ViewData["Contains"])
                    ))
                )
                .Scrollable(configurator => configurator.Height(500))
                .Navigatable(configurator => configurator.Enabled(true))
                )
```

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't read well.

I'm assuming the first part should read:

I have two `nullable double values `inside a Kendo Grid (Lat & Lon) and I want to edit them using Kendo's in-cell Editable mode. 

But the bit where you say what the issue is I'm afraid I couldn't decipher.

Are you trying to make both cells editable at the same time? Or having issues when Tabbing/clicking between cells/Issues when saving the data?